# Should I delete an on-hold question if I can't edit it to fit the rules?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I had [my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186293/how-can-i-output-random-points-under-a-laplacian-density-function-in-matlab) put on hold because off-topic, but I can't reword it to fit the site's rules. Shall I just delete it?

There is an upvoted correct answer and a wrong answer (with a discussion in the comments and finally edited to signal it was wrong).

Comment: With an up voted answer you're out of luck. You can't delete in that case.

Comment: I think it would be useful for you to include a link to your question because advice may be offered here that could help you think about other ways that you might be able to edit it to bring it on-topic.

Comment: Can you give context and post a link to the q?

Comment: @YosiDahari I'm guessing it's [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/186293) question on Cross Validated

Comment: @BenN Yes it's that one

Comment: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)